# Angular - how to get data without refreshing the page, like Google and Facebook?

Tags: angular

You can tell from the title I'm still learning.

I have an API that gets me employee objects, and an input field that gets you an employee by name.
So if I type "George" into the field, I want to see a dropdown list of all employees which have
"George" in their name, without needing to execute a GET request. Like Facebook's behavior
where you search a person's name and get data back in real time, or in Google where search results
are retrieved in real time.

How would I do this in Angular? I've got no idea where or how to start, and I have no idea what this functionality is called either

Below is some code of my "get employee by name" input field and button

```
<h3>Get employee by name:</h3>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter employee name" [(ngModel)] = "name">
<br>
<button (click) = "getEmployeeByName()">Get employee</button>
```

The functionality works, I get a list of employees back that are named "George", however, I want to display a preview in a dropdown list of all employees that match "George".

If there's no match, the dropdown list would say "no employees are found

Comment: I already tried that

Comment: How would I find this "right knowledge" when i don't know about it? I don't know what to search

Comment: @ThomasJungblut you saved the day once again dawg

Comment: Google, Facebook and such do make GET requests (kind of)

You're just not looking at them properly. 

That's what a WebSocket is used for : it sends a message to a server, and the server replies in real-time to the client. 

In short, you CANNOT make an autocomplete without having to do a GET request (kind of). And be cool in your answers, we're here to help you, with that attitude you will only get banned.

Comment: No problem mate, but still, be cool, no-one will want to help you in the future if you answer like that

Answer (score 1):

What you need seems to be something like that:

in your.component.ts file:

```
...
yourEmployee = //List of your employee
filteredEmployee = [];

getEmployeeByName() {
    this.filteredEmplyee = this.yourEmployee.filter(emp => emp.name == this.name);
}
...
```

in your.component.html file:

```
...
<select name="select">
  <option *ngFor="let emp of filteredEmployee" value="emp">{{emp.name}}</option>
</select>
...
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer brody, I have this implemented already, it isn't what I'm asking for

Comment: So, please, be more specific on what you need